# no me permite el acceso a un archivo jar

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de correr un archivo jar desde la consola, pero me envía el siguiente mensaje

Error: Unable to access jarfile diegojava.jar(Error: no se puede acceder al archivo jar diegojava.jar)

```
C:\Users\User>C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\diegojava\out\artifacts\diegojava_jar\diegojava.jar

C:\Users\User>java -jar diegojava.jar
```

Error: Unable to access jarfile diegojava.jar

Comment: agrega la ruta al jar para ejecutarlo.. si no, no sabe donde buscarlo...

Comment: No te moviste a la ruta del `jar`, creo que sería más bien: `java -jar C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\diegojava\out\artifacts\diegojava_jar\diegojava.jar`